# How to get Google Geocoding API's response in language other then default (fx.:Chinese)?

Tags: android, location, gson

i have do it for several times to get address by parsing the Google json which contain infomation of addres in Chinese.But when i show the address in my mobile ,it is all in English.

i get the json from the url below.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=wuhan&sensor=false

**EDIT:**
With help of an answer i wana share with working solution:

```
            StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            sb.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=").append(latStr).append(',').append(lonStr).append("&sensor=false&Accept-Language:zh-CN");
            String url=sb.toString();
            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

            String responseData="";
            try {
                HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                response.addHeader("Accept-Language", "zh-CN");
                HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((entity.getContent()),"UTF-8"));
                String line="";
                while((line=bf.readLine())!=null){
                    responseData=responseData+line;
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: where is the question? where is minimal sample of how you calling it(not even android code but at least what api do you calling with which parameters)

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=wuhan&sensor=false

Comment: this json is which i am parsing.

Comment: 1. see my answer 2. change your question (i mean add your first comment to it) so other will not downvote your question (and they doing this because you didn't provide all information needed to answer this question)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `Accept-Language` to reaquest because in default google API will return information in english
fx.:
`Accept-Language: zh-CN`

**EDIT** (coz OP is wandering about):

if you're using `java.net.HttpURLConnection connection;` then use:

`connection.setRequestProperty ( "Accept-Language", "zh-CN");`

if `org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet request;` then:

`request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "zh-CN");`

i've just tested it in [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

and for

```
GET /maps/api/geocode/json?address=wuhan&sensor=false HTTP/1.0
Host: maps.googleapis.com
Accept-Language: zh-CN
```

i get

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "武汉",
               "short_name" : "武汉",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "湖北省",
               "short_name" : "湖北省",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "中国",
               "short_name" : "CN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "中国湖北省武汉市",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 31.36126030,
                  "lng" : 115.08257280
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 29.96907670,
                  "lng" : 113.70228110
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 30.5930870,
               "lng" : 114.3053570
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 30.78745989999999,
                  "lng" : 114.6189880
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 30.34877210,
                  "lng" : 113.9817810
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: add Accept-Language: zh-CN in the end of the url?

Comment: Thank you so much.I am trying.

Comment: i have got the address  in Chinese .Thanks.